# accessing a object variable in PHP codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following piece of code in my Model:

```
public function getSite()
{
    $this->load->library('site');
    $data = array();
    $str = "SELECT * FROM sitematrix_sites";
    $query = $this->getQuery($str);
    if($query){ 
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $site = new Site();
            array_push($data, $site->load($row));
        }

        foreach($data as $site){
            $site->data['database'] = $this->getDatabase($site->data['site_id']);
            $site->data['baseline'] = $this->getBaseline($site->data['site_id']);
        }

        return $data;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And I created a class called site:

```
class Site{

public $data;

public function __contruct(){

    $this->data = ArrayObject(array(), ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST);

    $this->data['site_id']                      =   '';
    $this->data['site']                         =   '';
    $this->data['site_code']                    =   '';
    $this->data['tc_10']                        =   array();
    $this->data['tc9x']                         =   array();
    $this->data['tc8x']                         =   array();
    $this->data['tc2008']                       =   array();
    $this->data['eng_2005']                     =   array();
    $this->data['database']                     =   array();
    $this->data['baseline']                     =   array();
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Trying to get property of non-object</p>
<p>Filename: models/sitematrix_model.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 77</p>
```

Any thoughts? I have tried to access those values either as `$site->data->database` and as `$site->data['database']` but both don't work.

```
line 77:  $site->data['database'] = $this->getDatabase($site->data['site_id']);
```

The function getDatabase:

```
public function getDatabase($id){
    $database = array();
    $str = "SELECT * FROM site_database where site_id='$id'";
    $query = $this->getQuery($str);
    if($query){
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            array_push($database, $row->name);
        }
    }

    return $database;
}
```

Function getQuery:

```
public function getQuery($str){
    $data = array();
    $query = $this->db->query($str);

    if(!$query || $query->num_rows() == 0){
        return false;
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is line 77 exactly? And how about removing the "$this->data = ArrayObject...." ?

Comment: May a little `new` is missing?

Comment: I have updated my question, now you guys are able to see line 77:

Comment: what does the getDatabase() function contain?

Comment: the function getDatabase has been included

Comment: Whats in the function `getQuery`

Comment: Try changing the `$site` var in the `foreach($data as $site)` in the getSite() function, perhaps because you have declared $site in the first `foreach` and then again in the second `foreach` something is happening that shouldn't. Dont forget to change `$site->data['database']` and `$site->data['baseline']` also. Let me know what the results are.

Comment: It did not change much from what I had ... `$site` is a scope variable for the first `foreach`.

Comment: @xyz `echo $site->data`;
it does not look like php enjoys that piece of code, so I supposed it's something with `$data` in `Site`.

Comment: hmmm, I feel like I'm taking stabs in the dark a bit but maybe try `$site->data['database'][0]` just to see what that returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your error message is complaining about the

$this->getDatabase

part of that line, not the $site-> aspect.

Are all of these functions on the Model, not the Class site?

when you are working in the model, $this-> has to stick to functions & vars from that class

Comment: getDatabase is part of the model.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some investigation, I figured that `$site` is not a `Site`, but an Array.

`Array
    (
    [site_id] => 1

    [site] => Ames

    [site_code] => ame

    [windows_ref_unit_location] => \\plm\amnas\tc_ref

    [unix_ref_unit_location] => /tc_ref

    [windows_rte_location] => \\plm\amnas\tc_rte

    [unix_rte_location] => /tc_rte

    [windows_toolbox_location] => &lt;path-to-local-toolbox&gt;

    [unix_toolbox_location] => /tc_ref/TOOLBOX

    [UGS_LICENSE_SERVER] => 28000@cinxflex1,28000@cinxflex2,28000@cinxflex3

    [UGII_LICENSE_FILE] => 27000@cinxflex1,27000@cinxflex2,27000@cinxflex3

    [unix_dev_units] => /tc_work

    [unix_devop_path] => /usr/site/devop_tools

    [netapp_filer] => \\plm\amnas

    [perforce_proxy_path] => /p4p/p4p_cache

    [primary_contact] => Philomena Siddle

    [secondary_contact] => Mathieu Sarrazy

    [num_users] => 7

)`

Thus, there is not such thing like `$site->data['site_id']`, but `$site['site_id']`;